# В списке using отсутствует OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

Хотел начать работать с PhantomJS, установил через nuget сам Selenium, Selenium.PhantomJS. Однако в списке using он не появляется, если прописать вручную, подчеркивает как ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поддержка самого `PhantomJS` прекращена. Логично что и поддержка соответствующего ему драйвера также прекратилась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл решение.

Ставьте `Selenium.WebDriver` меньшей версии, например, **3.13.0**

> Предупреждение    CS0618  'PhantomJSDriver" является устаревшим:
>   'Development of PhantomJS has been discontinued, and the project
>   archived. The PhantomJS driver will be removed in a future release.